# ASP.NET: Why ALWAYS use 2 RequiredFieldValidator controls when validating 2 behaviors?

Tags: asp.net

I always wonder why to check (i)if a field is not empty and also (ii)if the user submitted the initial value presented to him, we always need 2 RequiredFieldValidators.

Is there any reason they made it that way? Why not just adding a **bool** property such as "**NullOrEmptyAllowed**", for instance?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You could always do a regex validator that does both parts of that.  But I would stick with the 2 separate validator for Required field, and for special formatting

Comment: That's exactly my question. Why? Is that for the same reasons as @Matthew Flaschen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably an application of the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: That make sens. But why did say probably?

Comment: @Richard, I didn't design the class, so I don't know for sure.